# Ассоциация с английского вопроса ведёт на удалённый вопрос

Tags: предложение, ассоциация-вопросов

В [этом вопросе на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/415511/5812238) есть ссылка на [ассоциированный вопрос на ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/641030/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F).

Однако, вопрос на ruSO был самостоятельно удалён автором.

Предлагаю его восстановить, так как это полезный вопрос (>1M просмотров на enSO), либо убрать ассоциацию.

Comment: Так задайте вопрос заново, ответьте, и перенаправьте ассоциацию на новый вопрос. Делов то.

Comment: Заодно я [предложил доработать](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303808/339911) механизм асссоциаций.

Comment: @alexolut хорошо, конечно, что предложили, но такую фичу вряд ли сделают, так как разные сайты. Разве что, будут кешировать ассоциации и периодически состояние проверять.

Comment: Хмм. Там видимо кто-то из модераторов еще комментарии все грохнул с критикой.